# Servlet runtime error: Want to know what could be the reason?

Tags: json, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

Code in servlet causing the error on runtime.

JSONArray parent = new JSONArray();

```
    int total=0;
    int count=1;
    int seatswon=0;


    while(rs.next()){
        count++;
        if(count>4){
            seatswon = rs.getInt(2);
            total += seatswon;          
        }
        else{
        JSONObject child = new JSONObject();
        seatswon = rs.getInt(2);
        String partyname=rs.getString(1);
        //System.out.println(partyname+"-"+ seatswon);
        total += seatswon;
        child.put("seatswon", seatswon);
        child.put("partyname", partyname);          
        parent.put(child);
        }

    }

    //total += total_others;
    DB.closeDB();
    JSONObject child = new JSONObject();
    child.put("seatswon", total);
    child.put("partyname","Total");

    parent.put(child);
    pw.print(parent);

    //System.out.println(parent.toString());
    pw.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [getLevel] in context with path [/Proect1] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONArray
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at api.akasalabs.nation.getNatLevel.doGet(getNatLevel.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0):

The jar containing the class `org.json.JSONArray` is not in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. So Tomcat can not find this class.

Comment: ohk so how to add it or do what you are saying sir ?

Comment: You recreate a war file (or exploded war structured) with the jar file containing this class put under WEB-INF/lib, and you redeploy it. If you don't know what a war file is and what its structured is, you should learn that before messing with servlets, because it's a pre-requisite.

Comment: Thanks it worked out but further errors have cropped up

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956) and more 
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)

Comment: That's an unrelated problem. First thing to do: stop using the JdbcOdbc driver, which should not be used for years, and is not even part of Java 8 anymore.

Comment: I know but this is an old project i have to debug it r8 nw and later i will be shifting it to mysql ... I m running it on jdk 1.7